# (C#, Asp .Net (mvc)) Как в форму веб приложения вывести заполнение полей класса с наследованием

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Опишу ситуацию на простых классах:
Есть класс Class1, он содержит коллекцию классов Class2. Есть так же классы Class2_1 и Class2_2, которые являются наследниками от Class2 и имеют свои уникальные поля.

Как мне составить форму веб приложения, где я смогу заполнять раздельно поля из Class2_1 и из Class2_2 и получать в контроллер объект класса Class1? (всё на одной странице)

В частности интересует приведение типа для полей формы.

Comment: можно использовать частичное представление: https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/7.5.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для таких ситуаций, в ASP.NET Core можно использовать различные способы, передавая вспомогательные данные из контроллера в представления это TempData,ViewBag и ViewData, но можно также использовать специальные сущности ViewModel, внутри которых могут быть сразу включены несколько объектов Model из вашей предметной области. Использование ViewModel позволяет следовать принципу строгой типизации представлений и не превращать код в вашем проекте в лапшу.
Для вашего абстрактного примера, для создания ViewModel, можно сделать так:

```
public class ClassesVM
{  public Class1 Class1 {get;set;}
   public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Class2SelectList {get;set;}
   public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Class2_1SelectList {get;set;}
   public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Class2_2SelectList {get;set;}
}
```

Для корректной работы у Вас уже должны быть корректно созданы основные Модели,
например модель-класс

```
Class1:
`public class Class1 
{public int Id{get;set;} 
 public string Name{get;set;} 
 public int Class2Id {get;set;} 
 public virtual Class2 Class2 {get;set;}
}`
```

, аналогично должны быть определены модели для всех подчиненных классов.
Также должны быть прописаны, соотвествующие атрибуты Аннотации Базы Данных для каждого из свойств, что бы можно было по ним корректно сформировать структуру таблиц в базе данных с помощью Entity Framework.
Далее, для получения возможности вывода на экран списков подчиненных объектов в представлениях, можно использовать специальный объект SelectListItem из библиотеки Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.
И в контроллере для создания новой сущности типа Class1 или для ее обновления, нужно извлечь из базы данных список существующих подчиненных классов, например,

```
    так:
    ClassesVM classesVM = new ClassesVM()
 {Class1 = new Class1(),
  IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Class2SelectList = _db.Class2.Select(
    i=> new SelectListItem{Text=i.Name, Value = i.Id.ToString()}), 
  IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Class2_1SelectList = _db.Class2_1.Select(
    i=> new SelectListItem{Text=i.Name, Value = i.Id.ToString()}), 
  IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Class2_2SelectList = 
   _db.Class2_2.Select(
    i=> new SelectListItem{Text=i.Name, Value = i.Id.ToString()})
 }
```

. После того как, актуальный экземпляр такой ViewModel, определен и в него подтянуты актуальные списки, существующих подчиненных классов, можно передать его в представление для создания нового экземпляра класса Class1. Вот в этом [репозитории](https://github.com/AndyBrizhak/Rocky/commit/62bc5e5eeb161461e4e4fd69d2807eeb746cdf04), решается аналогичная задача, когда для создания Товара, нужно подтянуть список возможных Категорий, к которому этот товар может быть отнесен, весь код написан для ASP.NET Core MVC под .NET 5. В описании к репозиторию есть  ссылка на видео, где показан конечный результат работы всего приложения, включая выпадающий список Категорий.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Я совсем не подумала про ViewModel) С ней проблема полностью решилась